# Blackmagic intensity pro is a virus. It crash motherboard + PCI + USB devices

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, 10.04, networking, capture

Blackmagic intensity pro is a virus. Do not buy this card anymore?

I bought a card and it crashed my whole system. I cant see network anymore getting up.

I tested this with: Ubuntu 10.04, 11.04, Fedora, CentOS, ArchLinux all the time it crashed my system.

- I cant boot to my own BIOS
- System do not show network or it does not get auto DHCP or no network interface
- CPU/RAM do not function properly

Has anyone same problem?

Comment: This is more of a discussion and experience sharing than an answerable question, so it is more suitable for a forum than this site. Please take it to ubuntuforums.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A piece of hardware, by definition, is not a virus. It can however, be incompatible with your current hardware, OS or other software. I would suggest you return this product, and purchase a comparable device that is compatible. (I'll post a link to the Ubuntu/Linux HAL here shortly.)
 You might also contact their company. I suggest you find their website for contact information. In your correspondence, you should include that you are a Linux user who would like to use their product, but you've had to return it due to the fact that they do not properly support a viable, and widely used Operating System. Also, that you will not purchase any further products until such matters are resolved.
Aside from that, @Javier Rivera make an excellent suggestion to visit http://ubuntuforums.org.
I've been a member there for some time and I'm sure there is someone there that would be glad to continue a discussion on this topic.